# Measurement panel goes to out side of the map and webpage

Tags: javascript, html, gis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I'm trying to create the simple web map application using esri samples javascript, but in my application the measurement panel is outside of the map and web page. The measurement div cannot pull in inside. How can I fix this?

Comment: Post the relevant code and what have you tried?

Comment: this is big code send the sample website, or any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

The location of the measurement widget is defined in the body of the html document, for exmaple:

```
    <div style="position:absolute; right:20px; top:10px; z-Index:999;">
```

For more information about ESRI Javascript measurement widget go to: http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/#sample/widget_measurement